# How to get a marker to move with its reference frame?

Tags: ros, rviz, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm learning how to use markers in `rviz`, currently using `ros noetic`. I successfully created a marker and can get it to show in `rviz` just fine, but when I move my model the marker stays in the same place in the space, it doesn't follow its reference frame. Any idea on how to fix this and get the marker moving with its respective reference frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390093/how-to-get-a-marker-to-move-with-its-reference-frame?/) by [jasr](https://answers.ros.org/users/87553/jasr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

are you using the `frame_locked` parameter of the [Marker msg](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html)?

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2021-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jasr](https://answers.ros.org/users/87553/jasr/) on 2021-11-05**:
Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

**Comment by [jasr](https://answers.ros.org/users/87553/jasr/) on 2021-11-05**:
As the user mcevoyandy commented, al I needed to do is to add the `frame_locked` parameter, so with only this set as true, the marker moves keeping its position relative to its reference frame:

> self.marker_object.frame_locked = True